# Razor Page Can't Validate Policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using VS 2019, ASP.Net Core 5 with Razor Pages (not MVC).
I have a simple Razor Page with Authorization Policy. The below is an extract from the code, I have simplified it a little for this post and replaced global constants with literals.

Razor Page Directive:

> [Authorize(Policy = "AuthUsers")]

The policy is described in Startup.cs

> services.AddAuthorization(options =>
> options.AddPolicy("AuthUsers", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Users")));

The Login Page creates the Claims principal with the above claim like this:

> var Claims = new List { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,
> Input.Email)) }; Claims.Add(new Claim("Users", "1"));
> var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(Claims,
> CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); ClaimsPrincipal
> claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

After a successful login, I verified that the claim has been setup correctly but each time I go to the razor page it returns to the login page to authorize, even though the user is clearly logged in and "Logout" link is active.

Comment: i changed the order but that did not help. I think at some point this was working until I introduced multiple login pages using Authenticationscheme.  I since then removed that to get the policy page working and moved my login page back to the default /Acoount/Login

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have these lines in this order:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The other way around like this:

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

is an explanation for the behaviour you describe. After succesfully authenticate the login you will never get authorization.